# Кириллица в XML файле

Tags: xml, http, flutter, dart

Возникла проблема с получением XML-файла с помощью get-запроса. Я не могу изменить файл. Его можно только получить.

```
http.get(Uri.http('www.cbr.ru', 'scripts/XML_daily.asp')).then((res) async {
  setState(() {
    xmlData = XmlDocument.parse(res.body);
    getDateOfUpdate(xmlData);
  });
});
```

Все символы кириллицы заменены на иероглифы (Например, Àçåðáàéäæàíñêèé ìàíàò).

Вот этот XML файл:

[image: Все символы кириллицы заменены на иероглифы (Àçåðáàéäæàíñêèé ìàíàò)]

Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Вы можете попробовать добавить декларацию XML Prolog следующим образом: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Дело в том, что я не могу изменить этот файл. Могу только получить его.

Comment: Если вы откроете этот XML-файл в Notepad++, в правом нижнем углу вы увидите кодировку файла (encoding).

Comment: Я по заданию не могу его изменять таким образом. Возможно ли изменить кодировку в самом GET-запросе? Сама строка из запроса возвращается с некорректными данными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробовал обратиться к сайту [www.cbr.ru](http://www.cbr.ru), он честно говорит, что отдает в кодировке windows-1251

```
<?xml
version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<ValCurs Date="04.10.2023" name="Foreign Currency Market">
    <Valute ID="R01010">
        <NumCode>036</NumCode>
        <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
        <Nominal>1</Nominal>
        <Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
```

отсюда наблюдаются два выхода, первый установить пакет типа этого:
https://pub.dev/packages/windows1251 и декодировать ( не проверял)

```
import 'package:windows1251/windows1251.dart';

void main() {
  // >>> 'Привет!'
  print(windows1251.decode([207, 240, 232, 226, 229, 242, 33]));
  // >>> [207, 240, 232, 226, 229, 242, 33]
  print(windows1251.encode('Привет!'));
}
```

второй вариант, обратиться к "зеркалу" сайта https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_utf8.xml, но это не официальный (см. [www.cbr-xml-daily.ru](http://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru)) это зеркало возвращает ответ в utf8

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


void main() {
  fetchData();
  
}

void fetchData() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_utf8.xml');
  var headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'http://www.wikipedia.org/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
  };
  var response = await http.get(url,headers:headers);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    
   var responseBody = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
   
    print(responseBody);
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ValCurs Date="04.10.2023" name="Foreign Currency Market"><Valute ID="R01010"><NumCode>036</NumCode><CharCode>AUD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Австралийский доллар</Name><Value>62,6975</Value><VunitRate>62,6975</VunitRate></Valute><Valute ID="R01020A"><NumCode>944</NumCode><CharCode>AZN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Азербайджанский манат</Name><Value>58,3928</Value><VunitRate>58,3928  ....
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нельзя этого сделать. Я могу его только получить.

Comment: А вы что открываете, что там символы не те, что ожидали?

Comment: Мне дали задание с этим файлом. Запрос возвращает res.body уже с неверными символами. Возможно ли как-то преобразовать HTTP-ответ? Извиняюсь за глупость. Я в этом деле новичок.

Comment: Можно, например, использовать другую ссылку https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily.xml

Comment: Всё равно не работает...

Comment: @ArtyomStepchuk ну получи его, сохрани в буфер, добавь кодировку и парси

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Я обратился к зеркалу сайта, затем использовал utf8.decode(res.bodyBytes). Все работает как надо.